# Android: SQLite Database "No such table exists"

Tags: android, sqlite

Android Development seems to be some sort of error-riddled bane for me thus far, so I once more return with a question.
I am creating a Database connection through SQLite, but I am getting the following error:

```
(1) no such table: TABLE_NAME
```

I have tried re-installing my app, renaming the .db file the app has to create and some other methods I found online, but none work. In total, I have been stuck with this for several days.

My code:

**MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setGlobalContext(this);
    SQL = new SQLLib(this);

    Button LoginBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
    LoginBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button RegisterBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register_btn);
    RegisterBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    newTab("Tag1", R.id.login, "Login");
    newTab("Tag2", R.id.newitem, "Nieuw");
    newTab("Tag3", R.id.viewitems, "Overzicht");

    getTabHost().setCurrentTab(0);
    hideTab(1);
    hideTab(2);
}
```

**Login function - attached to LoginBtn**

```
public void Login(){
    if(Username.replaceAll(" ", "") != "" && Password.replaceAll(" ", "") != ""){
        if(SQL.SelectString("SELECT PASSWORD FROM USERLOGIN WHERE USERNAME = '"+Username+"'") == Password){
            Message("Login");
        }else{
            Message(SQL.SelectString("SELECT PASSWORD FROM USERLOGIN WHERE USERNAME = '"+Username+"'")+", "+Password);
        }
    }else{
        Message("Not all data is inserted. Try again!");
    }
}
```

**Register function - attached to RegisterBtn**

```
public void Register(){
    if(Username.replaceAll(" ", "") != "" && Password.replaceAll(" ", "") != ""){
        if(SQL.SelectString("SELECT USERNAME FROM USERLOGIN WHERE USERNAME = '" + Username+"'") == ""){
            SQL.Insert("USERLOGIN", new String[]{"USERNAME", "PASSWORD"}, new String[]{"\""+Username+"\"", "\""+Password+"\""});
        }else{
            Message("User'"+Username+"' already exists!");
        }
    }else{
        Message("Not all data is inserted. Try again!");
    }
}
```

**SQLLib**

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "pwmanagement.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public SQLLib(Context context) {  
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {   
    db.rawQuery("CREATE TABLE userlogin (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, USERNAME TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT);", null);
    db.rawQuery("CREATE TABLE passwords (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, USERLOGIN INTEGER,  USERNAME TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT);", null);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void Insert(String table, String[] columns, String[] contents){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    if(columns.length == contents.length){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        for(int i = 0; i < contents.length; i++){
            values.put(columns[i], contents[i]);
        }

        db.insert(table, null, values);
    }

    db.close();
}

public String SelectString(String query){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String s = "";
    Cursor cursor;

    cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        s = cursor.getString(0);
    }

    db.close();
    return s.replaceAll(" ", "");
}
```

**Full LogCat of the error**

```
09-02 17:28:23.485: E/SQLiteLog(7569): (1) no such table: USERLOGIN
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569): Process: com.example.password, PID: 7569
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: USERLOGIN (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT USERNAME FROM USERLOGIN WHERE USERNAME = 'steven'
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:923)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:534)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:65)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1370)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1309)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at com.example.password.SQLLib.SelectString(SQLLib.java:62)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at com.example.password.MainActivity.Register(MainActivity.java:85)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at com.example.password.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:50)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4470)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18593)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
09-02 17:28:23.495: E/AndroidRuntime(7569):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So, my question is:
Where is this error coming from and how do I fix it? I followed the steps I found online and even in the books I own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong instruction, and you tables aren't created:

```
 db.rawQuery("CREATE TABLE...
```

should be:

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE...
```

`rawQuery()` is only used to execute **SELECT** statements (SQL **queries**). No other ones.
All other SQL **commands** are executed through `execSQL()`

Comment: Excuse me while I go feel like a doofus. Thanks a bunch, Frank.